# Angular: I need from swimlane ngx-graph all nodes

Tags: html, angular, graph, frontend

i need from the swimlane graph all nodes, which are current in the graph.
I know how i can get one node by a click, but i need every node with one click.

Below is the code for only one node.

```
<ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node >
   <svg:g (click)="changeColorOfNodes(node)"  ngx-tooltip [tooltipPlacement]="'top'" [tooltipType]="'tooltip'" [tooltipTitle]="node.position">
     <svg:rect [attr.width]="node.width" [attr.ry]="4" [attr.height]="node.height" [attr.fill]="node.options.color" />
    <svg:text alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="0" [attr.y]="node.height / 2">
     <svg:tspan text-anchor="middle" [attr.x]="node.width/2" [attr.y]="15" font-weight="bold">{{node.type}}</svg:tspan>
     <svg:tspan text-anchor="middle" [attr.x]="node.width/2" [attr.y]="35" font-weight="lighter ">{{node.label}}</svg:tspan>
   </svg:text>
  </svg:g>
</ng-template>
```